# When is a real function orthogonal to its derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this proof that a function $f$ is orthogonal to its derivative $f'$:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)f'(t)dt
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\Omega) (-j\Omega) F^*(\Omega) d\Omega
= -\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty j\Omega |F(\Omega)|^2 d\Omega
= 0
$$

where $F(\Omega)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f(t)$.

This clearly isn't true for all functions, e.g. $f(t) = \max(0,t)$. Could anyone help me figure out which assumptions were made? The original text was
not more specific than this.

Comment: Probably both $f$ and $f'$ ought to lie in $L^2$.

Comment: @Mark Are you considering only the case for $\omega(x) =1$?

Comment: @PeterT.off I don't follow, what's $\omega(x)$?

Comment: @Mark The weighing function. Not all [orthogonal functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalFunctions.html) have the same weighing function.

Comment: @PeterT.off: Aha. Yes, that's orthogonality in the room I'm considering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the assumptions that the integral even makes sense, this particular result is based on the assumption is that $f(t)^2$ is defined at $t = \pm\infty$ and that the two limiting values (at $t = \infty$ and $t = -\infty$) are equal.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)f^\prime(t)dt = \tfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tfrac{d}{dt}f(t)^2 dt = \tfrac{1}{2}f(t)^2|_{-\infty}^\infty
$$

Comment: By "$f(t)^2$ is defined at $t=\pm\infty$", are you referring to the limits at $\pm\infty$? And by making sense, do you mean that it converges?

Comment: Yes for both of them.